# Terraform: Attempting to use a "null_resource" fails

Tags: terraform

I have a working terraform script which I would like to add a null_resource local_exec command to. But when I do, it fails. Here's the block:

```
resource "null_resource" "es_lincoln" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo $(pwd) > somefile.txt"
  }
}
```

and when I uncomment it and try to execute a `plan` I get this error:

```
Error: Could not load plugin


Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".

Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be located,
don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.

Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".

Failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null" to
obtain schema: unknown provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null"
```

After googling for a while, I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem. Why is my Terraform attempting to match "null_resource" with a provider when it should just run its local-exec provisioner?

Comment: Have you run `terraform init` as instructed in the msg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`terraform init` is required if you change provider requirements or modules change.
Providers are required for each *resource* type, in this case `null_resource` requires the `null` provider.
If you change your code in such a way that a new provider is required, as in this case you uncommented your resource to make it active, then `terraform init` is required to run again.  You can see the changes in the `.terraform` directory in the terraform script directory.
It should be noted that if you add a second `null_resource`, you would not have to re-run `terraform init` again. -- unless you add a module ;-)

Comment: That was it! Wow. I assumed that the message saying I should run "terraform init" was an error because the project was already init'ed and I was just trying to add an exclusively local command. Pretty confusing naming convention but it works! Thanks!